# WhereHas dentro de un WhereHas

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un campo al que quiero acceder pero para esto necesito acceder a 3 tablas,  tabla 1(id, tabla2_id), tabla 2(id, tabla3_id), tabla 3(id,tabla4_id), tabla 4(id, tabla5_id).. Necesito acceder al id de la tabla 5 (tabla5_id) a través de la tabla 1, solo he conseguido llegar al campo tabla3_id con whereHas y he probado varias cosas con lo mismo para ver si puedo llegar hasta el registro de la tabla 4 pero no he podido.

```
    return Tabla1::with(['tabla2' => function($q){
        $q->with(['tabla3' => function($q){
            $q->with(['tabla4' => function($q){
                $q->with('tabla5');
            }]);
        }]);
    }])
    ->where(function($q) use($request, $texto){
        $q->where('id', '!=', 0);
        if(isset($request->tabla2_id)){
            $q->where("tabla2_id", $request->tabla2_id);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas("tabla2", function($q) use($request){
        if(isset($request->tabla3_id)){
            $q->where("tabla3_id", $request->tabla3_id);
        }
    })
```

El código de arriba si funciona a la perfeccion pero siguiendo este principio quisiera saber como puedo acceder a la tabla 4 con el registro tabla5_id, intente algo como esto pero no funcionó:

```
  ->whereHas("tabla2", function($q) use($request){
        $q->whereHas("tabla3", function($q) use($request){
            $q->whereHas("tabla4" Etc ///////)
        })
    })
```

Comment: ¿Son dos problemas distintos cada código que muestras o es el mismo problema?

Comment: en tu modelo crea las relaciones de cada tabla en reversa, y así en tu consulta normal haces un simple with(tabla2)
En el modelo de la tabla4 hacer tu relación con la tabla5.
En el modelo de la tabla3 hacer tu relación con la tabla4 incluyendo el with(tabla5).
En el modelo de la tabla2 hacer tu relación con la tabla3 incluyendo el with(tabla4).
En el modelo de la tabla1 hacer tu relación con la tabla2 incluyendo el with(tabla3).
y ahora si llamas el with de tu tabla1 y listo :D

Comment: @Shaz es un solo problema, el primer código muestra lo que me funciona y el segundo lo que intento pero no funciona, me disculpo si no se entiende.

Comment: @BrunoAngeles eso tengo hecho en los modelos, pero no quiero llamar datos, quiero consultarlos y ahi al hacer lo que me indicas no me funciona, no me permite consultar un valor de la tabla 5 a traves de la tabla 1, ese es el problema, logre hacerlo con el whereHas pero solo hasta la tabla 2

Comment: otra cosa que puedes intentar es hacer esa relación que te digo y después del get() hacer un where 
`modelo::whit(tabla1)->get()->where('tabla1.tabla2.tabla3.tabla4.tabla5', '=', 'lo que sea')`
aunque no creo que sea lo que busques tampoco ...
solo que la dividas en varios, pero eso lo hace muy lento y chafa, seguiré pensando a ver si consigo algo que te sirva